# Query (mysql) should only update if $sqltext < $_POST[Score]

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
$sqltext = "SELECT Score FROM HighScore ".
    "WHERE fbID='$_POST[fbID]' AND ".
        "Layout='$_POST[Layout]'";
$result = mysql_query($sqltext); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $sql = "UPDATE HighScore SET Score = '$_POST[Score]', ".
        "Time = '$_POST[Time]', ".
        "Stars = '$_POST[Stars]' ".
        "WHERE fbID = '$_POST[fbID]' AND Layout = '$_POST[Layout]'"; 
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO HighScore (fbID, Layout, Score, Time, Stars) ".
        "VALUES ('$_POST[fbID]','$_POST[Layout]',".
        "'$_POST[Score]','$_POST[Time]','$_POST[Stars]')";
}
```

What does it do? Well it checks if a row is in the database or not (there is always just 1 row or none). If there is no row, it inserts a new one in the database. If the row is present it will update the row. This all works OK.

$sqltext will give a value. This value can be 234, 3424342 or even -392. If this value is smaller than the '$_POST[Score]' value, it should update the row. Currently it doesn't and I can't seem to get this working properly. So how can I make it so, that if $sqltext (which is Score from the db) < '$_POST[Score]' it should update the row and else ignore it? (also not insert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqltext= "SELECT Score FROM HighScore WHERE fbID='$_POST[fbID]'AND Layout='$_POST[Layout]'"; $result = mysql_query($sqltext); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    if ($row['Score'] < $_POST['Score'])
    {
            $sql="UPDATE HighScore SET Score = '$_POST[Score]', Time = '$_POST[Time]', Stars = '$_POST[Stars]' WHERE fbID = '$_POST[fbID]' AND Layout = '$_POST[Layout]'"; 
    }
  }
}else{
            $sql="INSERT INTO HighScore (fbID, Layout, Score, Time, Stars) VALUES ('$_POST[fbID]','$_POST[Layout]','$_POST[Score]','$_POST[Time]','$_POST[Stars]')";
}
```

I think this is what you want. But it does not do anything, if there is a row AND the score is higher than the Score in POST['Score']

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I needed. One thing, when Score is higher then the post score, nothing happens. This is good. Only thing: it gives an error: Error: Query was empty. Is there a way to hide this error? Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you have a var `$sql` and you will execute this via `mysql_query($sql)` right? So just do a check before querying: `if (isset($sql) && !empty($sql)) { mysql_query($sql); }`

Comment: Hmm no luck with this one, perhaps I've placed it wrong? Must it be after the else{ ?

Comment: You have in your code a `mysql_query($sql);` just replace it with the code is posted in the comment and it should work fine. I think it is after the `else { ... }`, but I really can't guess your code :-)

Comment: I am using the code you suggested in your first post, but when I put the if just after the else {... it inserts the row in the db even if the score is smaller (where normaly the error should appear).... WHat am I not seeing?

Comment: Do you mean insert or update? Sure it will insert, if there is no row (`if (mysql_num_rows($result)> 0)` - the else belongs to this line). So: If you have score AND the score is lower than the score in db, `$sql` is not set, else it updates it. But if there isn't any score, the score will be inserted to the database. Maybe you could use a paste service to show your current code.

Comment: No no I ment the code from your first post = the code I am using right now. It works as it should, but it gives an error: `Error: Query was empty` when Score is higher then the `$_POST['Score']`. All I want is to hide this error. I can paste the code if you like, but it is exactly the same as in your post at the top

Comment: Yes, post it please. I'm sure doing the stuff with `if (isset($sql) ...` will fix your problem, but maybe you inserted it the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on `(fbID, Layout)` and then just use one query:

```
$sql = "
     INSERT INTO HighScore 
       (fbID, Layout, Score, Time, Stars) 
     VALUES ( '$_POST[fbID]', '$_POST[Layout]'
            , '$_POST[Score]', '$_POST[Time]', '$_POST[Stars]'
            )
     ON DUPLICATE KEY 
     UPDATE
           Score = GREATEST(Score, VALUES(Score))
         , Time = VALUES(Time)
         , Stars = VALUES(Stars)
       ";
```

Comment: Never used GREATEST before, this would be a nice way to expedient with it. Will play around with this code, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this gives an error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Score = GREATEST(Score, VALUES(Score)) , Time = VALUES(Time) ' at line 8

Comment: @Maurice: try now (removed the `SET`)

Comment: Note that the `Time` and `Stars` will still be updated with this exact statement (but the `Score` only if the new score is greater than the existing one).

Comment: Hmmm ok, but it should update all (so score, time and starts), but ONLY if the new score is greater than the existing one